# How to run sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' from PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, octopus-deploy

To enable 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' I can run the following statement in SQL. Does anyone know how to enable from PowerShell?

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure
```

Comment: Try `Invoke-SqlCmd`, pass `-ServerInstance` as your server and `-Database` as the database to run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, replacing `<SQL server>` and `<database name>` with the correct parameters for your environment:

```
$sql = '@
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure
'@

Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $sql -ServerInstance <SQL server> -Database <database name>
```

The syntax highlighting here doesn't help illustrate that `@' '@` denotes a 'here string', which allows all characters until `'@` as the first character on a newline denotes the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
$query = "
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure
"

Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $query -ServerInstance <Your Server Name>
```